# Redirect www to non-www on Azure Dns Zone

Tags: azure, redirect, cname, no-www, azure-dns

I have created Azure DNS Zone to manage redirections which use domain from namecheap.
Let's assume that my website is [www.johndoe.com](http://www.johndoe.com) and currently website working well for johndoe.com but when I call [www.johndoe.com](http://www.johndoe.com) it doesn't work well.
I have CNAME record and in CNAME redirect to redirect but unfortunately it doesn't work.
When I have call [www.johndoe.com](http://www.johndoe.com) response message is as following...

### Our services aren't available right now

We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please take into account that DNS *does not* provide a redirect.

An additional A or CNAME record only provides your IP address to people that navigate to that specific URL. When `www.johndoe.com` and `johndoe.com` both resolve to your web server, this means each page on your site has two addresses. This is horrible for things like SEO.

For a true redirect (and a 301 is preferred for SEO), set something up in the service that's handling the traffic coming in.

For instance: if you have an App Service running ASP.NET, setup the redirect in `web.config`. If you have Front Door (or a CDN) in place, use the rules engine to create a redirect with the correct condition and action.

Here's an example redirect in an Azure Front Door Classic Resource (this one redirects the other way):

[image: Azure Front Door Rules Engine redirect]